# Cannot build app in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Hello I have started work with firebase recently and stuck on one problem.

I am building small web app and I have connect this web app to firebase backend to read and write to databases.
Everything was ok and I had connection. I could put items to databases and get them by GET request. I have implemented simple authentication and that worked great too.
Suddenly today my app stops to build after 'ng serve' command in terminal window. I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./~/firebase/app/shared_promise.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill' in '/Users/me/Desktop/GMO/node_modules/firebase/app'
 @ ./~/firebase/app/shared_promise.js 22:35-62
 @ ./~/firebase/app/firebase_app.js
 @ ./~/firebase/app.js
 @ ./~/firebase/firebase-browser.js
 @ ./src/app/auth/auth.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I am sure that I didn't change anything inside firebase module.

Inside this ./~/firebase/app/shared_promise.js

there is a line there:

```
var PromiseImpl = scope.Promise || require('promise-polyfill');
```

and I have found that if I delete "|| require('promise-polyfill')" from it, the app works. Of course I don't want to do this, because this is element of module and I don't want to change it but I don't have any other idea...

Please advice!

Comment: Did you try `npm install promise-polyfill` and `npm install` in the root folder of your project?

Comment: @Andrew this works like a charm! Thank you! Spend almost whole day yesterday on that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Andrew, your solution is working:

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering, `--save-exact` will prevent updates to new versions of promise-polyfill (preventing them from breaking existing firebase code).